# Will a Cisco WS-X4548-GB-RJ45 switch module fit in a 3825 router chassis

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

I currently have a NME-XD-48ES-2S-P 10/100 switch module in my 3825 router and am looking to upgrade it to a 10/100/1000 switch.  I found a pretty good deal on the WS-X4548-GB-RJ45 switch module, but I can't figure out if it is compatible with the 3825 router.  Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, WS-X4548-GB-RJ45 is for a Catalyst 4500 switch, there is no way it is compatible with the Cisco 3800 series routers.

Second, there are no dense 10/100/1000 modules for the 3800.  If you need dense gige, buy a separate switch.

Comment: Is there a less-dense 10/100/1000 module for the 3800? I'd be OK with 8 or 16 ports

Comment: The NME-XD-48ES-2S-P has the most gige ports (2 sfp) but the 23 port version has a 10/100/1000 copper port.  Any real gige density requires an external switch...